# Django. get union of related querysets

Tags: django, django-queryset

The following is what I'm trying to do.
Of course this will be darn slow, and wonder if there's a better way of doing it.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = generic.GenericRelation(Bar)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Bar(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    invitation = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    meat = models.ForeignKey(Jessy)


bars = Bar.objects.none()
for foo in Foo.objects.all():
    bars = bars | Q(foo.bars.all())


bars.values('meat').order_by('timestamp'):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
Bar.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Foo), object_id__isnull=False).values('meat').order_by('timestamp')
```

That will query all `Bar` objects that have associated any `Foo` model.